# ECC RDIMM memory in MSI X99A Raider

Tags: memory, ecc

A hardware noob here.

I have a MSI X99A Raider motherboard which specification says the following:

- Support eight DDR4 DIMMs 2133/2200(OC)/2400(OC)/2600(OC)/2666(OC)/2750(OC)/3000(OC)/3110(OC)/3333(OC) MHz, up to 128GB Max.
- Supports Quad-Channel mode
- **Supports UDIMM ECC/ RDIMM memory modules**
- Supports Intel® Extreme Memory Profile (XMP)

I have a E5-2680 v4 CPU and some Micron PC4-2400T DDR4 ECC RDIMM modules. Based on the copied MOBO info above, I wonder these components are compatible with each other?

The spec. says supports UDIMM ECC / RDIMM mem. modules. How should I interpret this? It supports UDIMM ECC and RDIMM ECC or supports ECC with UDIMM modules only and non-ECC RDIMM modules? Can I use the above mentioned Micron modules with this MOBO?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.